# prometheus config file. Each target has diffrent bearer_token

Tags: prometheus

there is any option to set bearer_token for each target in prometheus config yml ?

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'example'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
      bearer_token: "TOKEN_A"
    - targets: ['localhost:9091']
      bearer_token: "TOKEN_B"
```

Do not work.
Any ideas ?

I can set it for job and it work but im interested on target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus [Configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration) is documented and can help you understand what's (not) possible.

You can configure an `authorization` section in [`scrape_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config), e.g.:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: {example}
  scrape_interval: 5s
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials: {token}
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - "localhost:9090"
```

Because the `authorization` section (and thus the `Bearer` credentials) are bound to `job_name`, if you want to use different `Bearer` credentials, you must use a different `job_name`, e.g.:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: {example-1}
  scrape_interval: 5s
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials: {example-1-token}
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - "example-1-1:9090"
    - "example-1-2:9090"
- job_name: {example-2}
  scrape_interval: 5s
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials: {example-2-token}
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - "example-2-1:9090"
    - "example-2-2:9090"
```

Comment: I would add that injecting authorization configuration in relabel_config is not implemented. See [issue #1176](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1176). This workaround is not available so there is no way around defining multiple jobs.